# Having trouble setting up syntax regions from lua

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, vimscript-lua

I'm running nvim v.0.8.1 on LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3.

In a lua config file I have:

```lua
vim.cmd[[syntax include @Yaml syntax/yaml.vim]]
vim.cmd[[syntax region yamlFrontmatter start=/^---$/ end=/^---$/ keepend contains=@Yaml]]
```

This does not seem to trigger Yaml highlighting in my markdown files. Running the same vim commands in the text editor works as expected.

I have tried the following:

- using vim.api.nvim_exec instead of vim.cmd.
- using single-line strings instead of multi-line string.
- using a multi-line string, chaining the commands together with `|`.

No errors are reported.
I have verified that the config file is being required properly, `print("test\n")` inserted above the vim commands causes neovim to display "test" on startup.

Thanks for any help, I really have no idea what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It was actually unrelated to vim, and it was a misconfiguration on my part, which a reader of this question could not have figured out. I was loading the markdown plugin after treesitter, so the syntax region command was being overwritten. By adding "yaml" to the list of treesitter plugins, we avoid the problem entirely, deferring instead to treesitter.

For any vimmers wandering cyberspace who happen upon this post, let it be a warning to you about unexpected interactions.